# PDFs go black & white when opened in Photoshop CC 2015.5

Tags: pdf, adobe-photoshop

I have noticed that very often when I open a PDF file in Photoshop, the image becomes black & white.

I am assuming this is somewhere in my settings; however, I don't know Photoshop well enough to know what to look for. Also, it doesn't happen with every document, but it does with most.

Answer (score 1):

I have never imported PDFs into Photoshop so I did some research.

It appears that if the PDF was not created in photoshop there is a [procedure to follow](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-opening-importing-images.html#open_pdf_files) when importing the PDF as Photoshop will need to rasterise the pages/images you are importing.

When you import there are **image size** options where there is also a **mode** setting.  The **mode** setting sets the [color mode](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/color-modes.html#color_modes) for the new document.